# Game Over and Pause/Resume taking care of the thread

Tags: java, android

I have a few issues I am having a hard time find good information on how to fix. First off I have a Game Over screen that shows up when it should. I have tried to use setting the Threads running to false so it stop running and then when the screen is touched to set it back to true, but it does not take the screen back to it running. Also I'm going to need to be able to actually clear all the times so that it resets it (what is a good way to do that). This similarly I will need I am assuming for the Pause and Resume. If running isnt set to false it appears to continue running even with sleep() just in slower increments. Here is my thread to see if you notice what I can do.

```
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {
   private GameView view;
   public static boolean running = false;
   static final long FPS = 10;


   public GameLoopThread(GameView view) {
         this.view = view;
   }

   public void setRunning(boolean run) {
         running = run;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
       long startTime;
       long sleepTime;
         while (running) {
                Canvas c = null;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try {
                       c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                       synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                              view.onDraw(c);
                       }
                } finally {
                       if (c != null) {
                              view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                       }
                }
                sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                try {
                       if (sleepTime > 0)
                              sleep(sleepTime);
                       else
                              sleep(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
         }
   }
```

}

Now this part is causing a large issue for the Pause/Resume. I have a handler.postDelayed handling the spawning of my sprites. Basically when the screen appears paused (cause it looks like it is if i use the sleep) the problem is that the handler (which is in the GameView) is seeming like the time is still running for it. Is there a way to reset it back to zero... preferably on both the classes for the Game Over and to pause the handler as well during the Pause? Thanks

EDIT: As of right now I'm trying to use an options menu to make a new game by making it reopen the activity that runs the game. It appears to reset it but it freezes it in the process. Anyone know how I can fix this?

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
   return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.newgame:  
        GameView.gameState=0;
        GameLoopThread.running=true;
        Intent game = new Intent(PlayGame.this, PlayGame.class);
        startActivity(game);
    break;
    case R.id.pause:        Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed Pause", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
    case R.id.quit: Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed Quit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Thats my options menu.

Answer (score 0):

This may not seem like the anwser you are looking for, but if you want to create code that's easily extendable (and learn a new desgin pattern!) then this is the way to go.

Most games use a State Machine for these kind of things.

For example

```
interface GameState{
    public void render(long elapsedTime);

}
```

Now you can create different states, like a MenuState, GameState, PauseState, OptionState, GameOverState, etc.

Some pseudo code to get the idea across:

```
State currentState = null;

public void run(){
   while(true){
        // Do your loop here
        currentState.render(time);
   }
}

public void setState(State state){
    currentState = state;
}
```

States Example:

```
public class MenuState implements GameState{
    public void render(long elapsedTime){
         //Render menu here
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class GameState implements GameState{
    public void render(long elapsedTime){
         //Render gameplay here
    }
}
```

currentState points to the current state and decides which one gets rendered/updated. Just change it's reference and your pause menu gets drawn.

This is a very common design pattern in games, search around!

Good luck!